# Libc Fatal signal: Ошибка доступа к памяти после вызова нативных методов в Android-приложении

Tags: android, память, android-ndk, jni, libc

В классе Application в статической области загружаю свою динамическую библиотеку, объявляю 2 нативных метода из этой библиотеки в этом же классе и в этом же классе вызываю один из них (метод `initialize()`):

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
private static ServerApi serverApi;
private static MyApplication instance;
public static final String LOG_TAG = "my_tag";

static {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("sdk");
    }catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
    instance = this;
    PrefManager prefManager = new PrefManager(instance);
    prefManager.setRun(true);

    initialize();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://xxx.xxx.com")
            .addConverterFactory(new NullOnEmptyConverterFactory())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(getHttpClient()) 
            .build();

    serverApi = retrofit.create(ServerApi.class);

}

public static ServerApi getApi() {
    return serverApi;
}

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}

public static Context getContext(){
    return instance.getApplicationContext();
}

private OkHttpClient getHttpClient(){
    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    builder
            .connectTimeout(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    builder.addInterceptor(chain -> {
        Request original = chain.request();
        Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder();
        requestBuilder.header("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        requestBuilder.method(original.method(), original.body());
        Request request = requestBuilder.build();
        return chain.proceed(request);
    });
    return builder.build();
}

public native int initialize();

public native void request();}
```

Сам нативный метод отрабатывает правильно, но после его выполнения появляются ошибки доступа к памяти (часто - разные) подобного вида: 
 1)

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 13708 (Measurement Wor)
A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
A/DEBUG: Abort message: 'Invalid address 0x7f900d6000 passed to free: value not allocated'
```

2)

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x879e803b20 in tid 16030 (op.applic)
2019-08-07 08:32:22.044 16084-16084/? A/DEBUG: pid: 16030, tid: 16030, name: op.applic  >>> com.sfsdffaa.develop.develop.applic <<<
2019-08-07 08:32:22.044 16084-16084/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x879e803b20
```

При этом, ошибка иногда появляется, а иногда нет. Приложение соответсвенно, вылетает. Очевидно что проблемы с памятью, но как отследить, где конкретно? Как можно более менее точно узнать что за адреса и что он по этим адресам ищет?

**UPD**
1) Внутри самой библиотеки вся память подчищается, поэтому утечка маловероятна.
При тестировании данной библиотеки на новом пустом тестовом приложении все корректно работает - значит проблема, возможно, в нехватке памяти при отрисовке конкретных вьюх. Но как понять где именно?
2) добавление в манифест `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` не помогло

Comment: Могу только сказать, что очень часто сталкивался с ошибкой "signal 11" при рисовании на определенных устройствах и версиях ОС (из-за ошибок в самой ОС). Рекомендую вычислять методом исключения Views.

Comment: @Style-7 А почему тогда все вьюхи работают, если убрать вызов нативного метода? Хватает памяти на прорисовку?